# Get file type json from bucket (Google Cloud Storage) to upload it and save it in VM instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

In order to read a new file(json content) from bucket and send it to vm instance using Cloud Functions, I have tried the following code I got the below error.

```
import requests
import json
import ndjson
from google.cloud import storage

def hello_gcs(data, context):
    """Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.  
    Args:
        data (dict): The Cloud Functions event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata of triggering event.
    Returns:
        None; the file is sent as a request to 
    """
    print('Bucket: {}'.format(data['bucket']))
    print('File: {}'.format(data['name']))

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(format(data['bucket']))
    blob = bucket.get_blob(format(data['name']))

    contents = blob.download_as_string()

    headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }

    data = ndjson.loads(contents)
    print(data)
    response = requests.post('10.0.0.2', headers=headers, data=data)
    return "Request has been sent"
```

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 383, in run_background_function _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 214, in call_user_function event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File "/user_code/main.py", line 30, in hello_gcs data = ndjson.loads(contents) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ndjson/api.py", line 14, in loads return json.loads(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 361, in loads return cls(**kw).decode(s) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ndjson/codecs.py", line 9, in decode return super(Decoder, self).decode(text, *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear to me:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Your file probably does not contain valid json (or possibly ndjson in this case).

Also you post to 'internal_IP_of_vm_instance' which can never be a valid url.

Comment: it was because of not valid ndjson, Thank you for your notice!